# Can no longer boot to RAID array after update

Tags: arch-linux, boot, raid, mdadm, mkinitcpio

I recently updated my system and after a reboot I get the following:

```
ERROR: device ‘UUID=...’ not found. Skipping fsck.
mount: /new_root: can’t find UUID=...
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
```

My root file system is on a RAID array and running `blkid` from the emergency shell shows that the array is not listed.

I have `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdb2` in RAID1 and typically it mounts to `/boot`. They have a `UUID="b45...` and are assembled into `/dev/md1` with a `UUID="436...`. While `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sdb3` in RAID0 typically mounted to `/`. They have a `UUID="8dc...` and are assembled into `/dev/md2` with a `UUID="d0d...`. The error at boot is looking for `d0d...`.

I booted to live USB and ran `blkid` and the array was there. So I mounted the arrays, `proc`, `sys`, `dev`, and and `boot`. I checked `/etc/mdadm.conf` and saw that all the `ARRAY` lines were commented out so I ran:

```
# mdadm --detail --scan >> /mnt/etc/mdadm.conf
```

I checked that the UUIDs matched the two partitions I am using in the arrays (`b45...` and `8dc...`). I then `chroot`ed in.

I then checked `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` and saw that `mdadm_udev` was missing from the `HOOKS` setting. So I readded that.

From there, I tried each of the following followed by a reboot:

```
# pacman -S linux
# mkinitcpio -p linux
# mkinitcpio -P
```

For each I can see it build the `mdadm_udev` hook and it tells me that:

> `Custom /etc/mdadm.conf file will be used in initramfs for assembling arrays`

But when I reboot, I get the same error and using `blkid` in the emergency shell shows that my RAID arrays are not listed (but the partitions that make it up are there and the UUIDs match what is in `mdadm.conf`) .

I also added the kernel parameter `raid0.default_layout=2` with the same result. It's never been there before but the wiki seems to indicate that I need it.

The Linux package is `linux-5.12.6.arch1-1` and before the ERROR on boot it tells me that it is:

> `Starting version 248.3-2-arch`

What am I missing that is causing the array not to be assembled on boot?

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea what caused the issue in the first place. But the solution was dead simple and I feel dumb.

The issue was that I had run:

`# mount /dev/md1 /mnt/boot`

from the live USB before `chroot`ing and running `mkinitcpio` because I wanted to check the settings in grub. So the `initramfs` image I created with `mdadm` was on a RAID array. The `initramfs` that got loaded had no clue about `mdadm` and so wasn't building the array.

Solution was to run `mkinitcpio` in `chroot` WITHOUT mounting an array to `/boot`.